# JQuery - object.id is undefined when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with JQuery and i'm running into this strange (or perhaps stupid) error.

In my HTML I have:

```
<input type="password" name="repeatPassword" id="id_repeatPassword" />
```

And then in my javascript code i have:

```
validateRepeatPassword($('#id_repeatPassword'));
```

Unfortunately in the function "validateRepeatPassword":

```
function validateRepeatPassword(o) {
        // this works
        if (o.value == $("#id_password").val()) {
        // this returns "undefined"
        alert(o.id)
...
}
```

why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

o is a reference to a jQuery object, NOT a DOM element reference. Inside your validateRepeatPassword function do:

```
alert( $(o).attr('id') );
```

If you want to access the direct DOM element's property from the jQuery object,

```
alert( o[0].id )

alert( o.get(0).id );
```

Comment: I know that, but wrapping it around inside the function would make it more lenient in that it would also accept DOM Elements in the argument. It's not a huge deal.

Comment: cool, but is there a way to use jQuery to retrieve the obeject as a DOM element reference instead?

Comment: Yes. you can use [0] or .get(0)..

alert( o[0].id )
or
alert( o.get(0).id )

Answer (score 2):

Inside your function `o` is a jQuery object, you should grab the id with the [attr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) function of of `o`.

```
alert(o.attr('id'));
```

But if you want to work directly with the DOM element on your `validateRepeatPassword` function, you can pass a reference to the element:

```
validateRepeatPassword($('#id_repeatPassword').get(0));
```